# generating random string which is collision free

Tags: php, random

I am using the below code to generate random string which I then insert to the database, and I would like to know if it is collision free? Is there a better way that is collision free?

```
function generate_random_name() 
{
$length = 12;
$charactersa = "mRdxIU2r3dxa1B2c3D4e5F6g7H8i9Jqk1L2m13N1oF5P6qW7R1Ls9T20u21V2w3X4y2Z2x6";
$real_string_legntha = strlen($charactersa) - 1;
$stringa=rand(12345,09876);
for ($oluvica = 0; $oluvica < $length; $oluvica++)
{
    $stringa .= $charactersa[mt_rand(0, $real_string_legntha)];
}
return $stringa;

}
$unique = generate_random_name();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `uniqid()` [With **`more entropy`** flag enabled] coupled with `time()`

```
<?php
echo uniqid(time(), true);
```

This will be more than enough. Coupling hashes like sha-256 and sha-512 will generate more unique outputs.

Some more [`info`](http://w3resource.com/gallery/creating-unique-ids-with-php-uniqid-function)

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. Good answer ;-)

Comment: so I should make it `$stringa .= uniqid($charactersa[mt_rand(0, $real_string_legntha)]);`?